# How can I get access to parameters passed to the program in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have 4 processes in which are related to each other. In the first program, I have a function in which it gets input from the user and then execute the second program. The following function execute the second program:

```
void MainWindow::ExecuteCuiMode(QString arg_username, QString arg_password, QString arg_domain, QString arg_computer_name, QString arg_ui_type)
{
    QString FinalUsername = "user:";
    QString FinalPassword = "ntlm:";
    QString FinalDomain = "domain:";
    QString FinalComputerName = "pc:";
    QString FinalUIType = "ui:";

    FinalUsername.append(arg_username);
    FinalPassword.append(arg_password);
    FinalDomain.append(arg_domain);
    FinalComputerName.append(arg_computer_name);
    FinalUIType.append(arg_ui_type);

    QString Arguments = FinalUsername + " " + FinalPassword + " " + FinalDomain + " " + FinalComputerName + " " + FinalUIType;
    if(ShellExecuteA(NULL, NULL, "Backend.exe", Arguments.toStdString().c_str(), NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL))
    {
         statusBar()->showMessage("Program Status: Connected to " + FinalComputerName);
    }
    else
    {
        statusBar()->showMessage("Program Status: Connection Failed.");
    }
}
```

In the second program (Backend.exe), I try to access to parameters which passed to the program like the following example:

```
QString firstArgument = QApplication::arguments().at(1);
QMessageBox::information(this, "Message", firstArgument);
```

but when the second program executed, it shows me nothing. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: which qt version are you using?

Comment: Qt Creator 4.11.1 Based on Qt 5.14.1 (MSVC 2017, 32 bit)

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#details)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is such a subtle point that the arguments that QApplication does not handle are simply deleted and those that don't work with them are equal to 1 so it’s not a fact that 1 will be the arguments that you want, I think that you need to call

```
 QStringList QCoreApplication :: arguments ()
```

and looked if there are any is that argument on the list?